# Replace booleans randomly in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, replace, series

I have a pandas series such as the following:

```
A     False
B     True
C     False
D     True
E     True
dtype: bool
```

that contains exactly two falses. I would like to flip one of the False values randomly to a True. Alternatively, how can I change the first or second occurrence to True. I tried the replace function but it changes everything to True. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit :**

Would have expected the following to do the job:

```
mask.ix[mask==False][np.random.randint(2)] = True
```

Comment: Do you want to change exactly one of them to a True or do you want to randomly reassign each value that is False, which in your example could result in 0, 1, or 2 of them being "replaced".

Comment: @pzp Mots importantly I am interested to know how can I randomly replace only one false to true.  so the output of my example would be either True, True, False, True, True - or - False, True, True, True, True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly more concise solution is:

```
mask[~mask].iloc[np.random.randint(2)] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by:

```
mask[mask.index[mask==False][np.random.randint(2)]] = True
```